# How to do "round half up" in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, rounding

I have some question when doing tf.round(x)  x=[0.4, 1.5, 2.5, -1.5, -2.5, -0.4]

If I want to get the ans=[0, 2, 3, -2, -3, 0] rounding half  way away from zero

How should I do?
I've tried tf.keras.backend.round(), tf.math.round, tf.math.rint()

I got similar answer in python but not in TF

```
>>>decimal.Decimal(101.5).quantize(decimal.Decimal('0'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
Decimal('102')
>>>decimal.Decimal(102.5).quantize(decimal.Decimal('0'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
Decimal('103')
>>>decimal.Decimal(-101.5).quantize(decimal.Decimal('0'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
Decimal('-102')
>>>decimal.Decimal(-102.5).quantize(decimal.Decimal('0'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
Decimal('-103')
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
x=tf.constant([0.4, 1.5, 2.5, -1.5, -2.5, -0.4])
x=tf.where(x>0, tf.math.nextafter(x, np.inf), tf.math.nextafter(x, -np.inf))
x=tf.round(x)
```

this will round away from 0.

Comment: Thanks @Default picture help to answer this question so quickly.
The answer which I want is correct. =)  
Verify and PASS

Comment: Note that this solution also rounds values like `1.4999999999999998` (which is strictly less than `1.5`) to `2.0` instead of to `1.0`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Yes, but it's impossible to represent 1.5 exactly anyway

Comment: Does tensorflow have some function let me make 1.499999999 to 1.4999 (only get  % .4f) , then I can get the answer as 1?
I've checked the answer in 1.4999999 is to 2    and in 1.499999 is to 1

Comment: @E.K. float32 precision is only 8 digits, so that's the result of floating point error. 1.5 rounds to 2, 2.5 rounds to 2

Comment: @Defaultpicture: "it's impossible to represent 1.5 exactly" <- Not in IEEE 754 binary32 or binary64 floating-point. 1.5 is exactly representable in every commonly-used binary, decimal, or hexadecimal floating-point system that I'm aware of. (1.1 is a different matter, of course)

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
x = np.array([0.4, 1.5, 2.5, -1.5, -2.5, -0.4]) 
for i, val in enumerate(x):
   if val % 1 == 0.5
       x[i] = tf.math.floor(x[i]) if val < 0 else tf.math.floor(x[i]+0.5)
   else
       x[i] = tf.math.round(x[i])
print(x)
```

> [ 0.  2.  3. -2. -3. 0.]

Comment: Thank you @Darshan
Yes, I want the last value be "0".
|-0.4| = 0.4 < 0.5   near to zero, ans = 0
|-0.6| = 0.6 > 0.5   away from zero, ans = -1

Comment: Yap, you solved my question~  Thanks a lot for your help ^^